# Forward (f) and backward (b) in label in SPIM not working

Tags: assembly, mips, spim, pcspim

I'm using PCSpim and it doesn't seem to support labels with f and b on the end. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: If it doesn't support those, use normal labels.

Comment: I'm making a compiler which target code is mips assemly. I need this feature so that my compiler won't have to generate so many labels for different control structures.

Comment: How about you use gnu assembler not spim, then.

Comment: I tried to do that but I can't produce correct results. I am using windows and i have MinGW on my computer. Can I use the gcc of MinGW. If yes, what specific command should I enter in the command-line. Tnx!

Comment: mingw is for x86, you need the gnu toolchain targeting mips. No idea if there is a windows build of that.

Comment: Building the GNU binutils for MIPS on a Windows machine isn't all that difficult or time-consuming. Install Cygwin, then download and unpack the binutils source code, configure with something like `./configure --target=mips-elf --prefix=/usr/local/mips-elf --disable-multilib --disable-nls --disable-shared --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld`, and then `make`

Comment: @Michael - I tried to do what you suggested but cygwin says "./configure: no such file or directory"

Comment: Well, you have to `cd` into the binutils source directory first.